# Customizing The Default Breadcrumb Separator in SharePoint 2013 With CSS Entities

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a breadcrumb in my Custom SharePoint 2013 Master-Page using the below code snippet.

```
<!--MS:<asp:sitemappath runat="server" sitemapproviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider" rendercurrentnodeaslink="false" hideinteriorrootnodes="true">-->
                <!--ME:</asp:sitemappath>-->
```

The separator within that is SharePoint's default one. But I want it to be replace with this CSS (ISO) entity ' \203A '.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks and regards, 
Chiranthaka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify simple separators, use *PathSeparator* property. If you need advanced separators, use *PathSeparatorTemplate*.

Following link contains example of how to work with template: http://asp-net-example.blogspot.cz/2009/04/how-to-use-path-separator-template-in.html